# euca run instances internal error

Tags: cloud, instance, instances, eucalyptus

A weird problem I am facing when trying to run instance on eucalyptus 
have searched hpcloud doc as well but everything seems ok. 
that is the problem here.

```
[root@localhost .euca]# euca-run-instances -k sshlogin emi-de196283

euca-run-instances: error (InternalFailure): Internal Error.
```

Here everything seems good.

```
[root@localhost .euca]# euca-describe-nodes
warning: euca-describe-nodes is deprecated; use ``euserv-describe-node-controllers'' instead
NODE    cluster1        172.16.34.11    ENABLED 
[root@localhost .euca]# euca-describe-images
IMAGE   emi-de196283    mybucket/centos.raw.manifest.xml    000416648029    available   private x86_64  machine             instance-store  hvm
```

what could be the possible problem for this error?

ADDED ERROR log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Networking not initialized
at com.eucalyptus.network.DispatchingNetworkingService$__clinit__closure4.doCall(DispatchingNetworkingService.groovy:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor244.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.describeFeatures(Unknown Source)
```

another thing is that

```
euca-describe-addresses
```

shows no output !!

Answer (score 0):

As there is no indication of the cause for the error from euca-run-instances you should check the cloud-error.log on the cloud controller host after running the command.

You do not say what version you are using, but here is the log documentation for 4.2.2:

http://docs.hpcloud.com/eucalyptus/4.2.2/#troubleshooting-guide/ts_logs.html

Comment: have added my error log and another thing that i noticed later describe  addresses doesn't return  any value.